# git returns "fatal: Invalid proxy URL 'http://'" on every pull or clone command

Tags: git, proxy, fatal-error

Today I wanted to update one of a git repository from github with the "git pull" command, and it gave me :

```
fatal: Invalid proxy URL 'http://'
```

I tried to re-clone that repository in an other place and gave me the same results. I tried an other repository, still the same. I erased all my user config about git, nothing changed, I event create an other user, nothing.

The only way I can make it work was by using "sudo git xxx".

I reinstalled git packages, and everything related to it. I searched the message on Google, there is only few page talking about that message.

I'm not using any proxy, I never used proxy with git either.
I'm lost...

My system is a Debian testing up to date.

Is there someone who ever had this problem before ?

Comment: `{ set; git config -l; } | grep -Fi proxy`

Comment: UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
ftp_proxy=http://
http_proxy=http://
https_proxy=http://

Comment: If I do the same command on an other computer I got : UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
ftp_proxy=http://
http_proxy=http://

Comment: how can I change or remove https_proxy ?

Comment: In the local terminal just `unset https_proxy`. To remove it globally forever you need to find out where from the settings come. `grep -Fr http_proxy /etc 2>/dev/null`, for example.

Comment: Found it, they came from /etc/environement, but I don't know why this file has been updated ... I commented out all lines.   Thank you !